# Changing ng-model value when using ng-repeat and $index

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a set of divs, inside a ng-repeat. When I use a ng-model for these, they are all updating when I change the value of this model from a function in the controller. i.e., If I change the model, all the divs are reflecting the same value.

Html:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="aw in aws">
<div ng-model="currentValue" ng-init="initializeSelects(aw.id)">{{currentValue}}</div>
```

Controller code:

```
$scope.initializeSelects = function(awId)
{
 $scope.currentValue = "read";
}
```

I tried changing my code to:

```
   <tbody ng-repeat="(i, aw) in aws track by $index">
 <div ng-model="currentValue[i]" ng-init="initializeSelects(aw.id, i)">{{currentValue[i]}}</div>
```

and

```
$scope.initializeSelects = function(awId, i)
{
     $scope.currentValue[i] = "read";
}
```

In this case, currentValue always is undefined and the model value can not be changed. Why would it be undefined?

Any inputs would be helpful, thanks in advance!

Comment: this seems like an odd place to use `ng-init`.  Also, it's not really clear what you are trying to accomplish here, without seeing what `aws` is, and what your expected output should be.

Comment: At beginning `$scope.currentValue` is a string...but then you want it to be array later. Not really clear what you are trying to do. Broken code isn't a good substitute for a proper explanation of what is expected

Comment: Provide a [mcve], a plunker demo would also be helpful